PowerBi AppOwnsData with service principal sample application from github giving 'unauthorized 401 error
I am completely lost, searching all the settings which should be implemented but still getting this error. I Then checked API call's header X-PowerBI-Error-Info. What I found there was: ServicePrincipalIsNotAllowedByTenantAdminSwitch.
So, my tenant's admin switched on "Allow service principals to use with Power BI APIs" and apply it to security group where service principal resides.
All the API permissions are in place. i gave access to both security group as well to the service principal to my workspace. What can be still missing?

I suggest you go through this documentation and verify if all steps are followed.  After the Setting is turned on, wait for 15minutes it will take some time to reflect.

I followed everything , everything seems correct. Now on developer tool i could see in my lib jquery.min.js and powerbi.min.js is missing. How to install these? as these are missing in the solution folder themselves.

powerbi.js will be coming from the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/powerbi-client. Provide additional details on how you're embedding, I might help

I solved the issue i have added the missing library contents and was still getting "ServicePrincipalIsNotAllowedByTenantAdminSwitch" . Then i checked with our Tenant admin he assigned all the permissions requested by me but to a wrong security group. And hence i faced this error. But now it's resolved.

Glad, it worked out

I am facing the same issue. I have followed the Azure documentation. Created a security group, created a service principal (App registration), assigned all the API permissions, added the security group and the service principal to the workspace as an Admin Member.
My Power BI admin also added the security group in the Power BI Admin portal tenant settings.
I still get this error when trying to fetch the embed token.
I get the access token fine using the client id and secret. Is there anything to check in the access JWT?

Check if you have provided admin consent to your application in the Azure Active Directory.
For more details refer to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78704981/17731710
